# How to parse a string and store it in different variables [Javascript]?

Tags: javascript, arrays

my problem is the next one :

I have a string with a special character that 'separates' the string in different parts.

```
var str = "this could be part 1 -- this is part 2 -- here is part3";
```

Here i chose '--' as special group of characters to delimit the parts.
And i would like from this string to be able to separate these parts and put one of each in an array and get this result :

```
this could be part 1 , this is part 2 , here is part3
```

What is the better way to do this ?

Thank you in advance for your answer

Comment: Have you tried something? I'd suggest doing some research, like what the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) function does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answer is IMHO too rediculously complicated for just this.

here I hope it's easier too understand:

```
// watch out for spaces, it's a usual mistake
var str = "this could be part 1 -- this is part 2 -- here is part3";

/* this extracts the parts between the ' -- ' and 
puts them in an indexed array starting from 0 */ 
var result = str.split(" -- ");
```

if you want to spit out one of them use it like this:

```
alert(result[0]);  // first index returns 'this could be part 1'
```

[check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Dezain/n44uke8L/)

Answer (score 1):

var individualValues = str.split(" -- ");

Comment: This answer would be better if you added some explanation as to how it would help the OP. As it is, it will likely enter the "Low Quality" review queue due to its brevity.

Comment: Thank you, i found more explanations here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp

Answer (score 0):

.split() just returns an array, so you can easily assign new variables using that.I would create a function along these lines.

```
function parse_string(theString) {
    var stringSplit = theString.split(“ -- ");

    var stringParts = {
            first  : stringSplit[0],
            second : stringSplit[1],
            third  : stringSplit[2]
        };
return stringParts;
```

}

Then you can call it anytime you need to parse a string.

```
var parsedString = parse_string("this could be part 1 -- this is part 2 -- here is part3

alert(parsedString.first); // should alert "this could be part 1"
alert(parsedString.second); // should alert "this is part 2"
alert(parsedString.third); // should alert "here is part3"
```